# Classes and Files VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have close to 150 reference tables and I am working on the service which would get the reference lists. I am trying to write a code generator and would like to know if there are any performance related problems if I have multiple classes in one file. I know that it would be difficult to maintain one huge file. But I am more concerned over performance than maintenance.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Raja

Comment: Rather than writing a code generator, I strongly suggest you look at [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: Take a look at CodeSmith/NetTiers too. Are the "reference tables" similiar? Are they relational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll make no difference to the compiled code. I do this all the time in Protocol Buffers with the generated code - admittedly that's C#, but it's the same principle.

It may well make Visual Studio slow if you ever *open* that generated code file, e.g. for debugging, but that's a different matter. (I believe Visual Studio on its own isn't too bad, but I seem to remember that Resharper slows down with big files. Apologies to Jetbrains if I'm misremembering this!)

From the point of view of making the generated code easier to include in project files etc, it's handy to have just a few large files rather than lots of small ones, so it sounds to me like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. I can now move ahead with confidence :-).

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no performance penalty or benefit to placing more than one class in a file.

There would be a maintenance cost associated with it, as it could make the class you want to edit harder to find.